# when i create a button with identifier,action parameters is giving error

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

stop = [[UIButton alloc] style:UIButtonTypeCustom target:self identifier:stop action:@selector[webView stopLoading]];

when i am using this is giving syntax eerror : is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is `@selector(stopLoading)`